# Number Keyboard and input type="text"

Tags: javascript, html, touch

Does anyone knows how to show automatically the number keyboard on `input type="text"` on touch devices?

I can't use `input type="number"` because of german number format with dots and commas like 1.000.000,00

It's for the javascript tool [heizkostenrechner.eu](http://heizkostenrechner.eu) and there are so many input fields and a solution would improve the usability very much.

Answer (score 0):

to set the `EditText` characters

```
yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

you can use class with a flag to create decimal like:

```
yourEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

but it wont add ',' to it

check [Input Types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) for more information about types of flags and classes

however if you want to add numbers and ',' and '.' you can use this code

```
yourEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.,"));
```

this will allow 0123456789 and '.' and ',' and you can add more characters if you want.